# How to download image in flutter which comes through APIs?

Tags: flutter, dart, download, flutter-dependencies

> Here I want to download image which comes through APIs in Flutter. I set edit image functionality and download that edited image. I mean I want to download image with set different widgets on image.
>
> How to accomplish this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Network image to display image Urls that are returned from an API:

```
const Image(
image: NetworkImage('YOUR IMAGE URL HERE'),
)
```

Comment: I do not want to display image, I want to download edited image.

Answer (score 0):

You can check;
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

Shortly:

```
final taskImage = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your url',
  savedDir: 'download path',
  showNotification: true, // Show download progress
  openFileFromNotification: true, // Click on notification to open file
);
```